# Calculate coefficient of variation in pivot table (Excel)?

Tags: excel, pivot, calculated-field

Is there any way (besides power pivot or fields calculated outside the pivot) to calculate the coefficient of variation (standard deviation/average) in a pivot table?
When I create a calculated field with

```
=STDEV('Field')/AVERAGE('Field')
```

it doesn't give me any values in the pivot table.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you please post a sample of the data sheet, pivot, expected/desired responses. Thank you

Comment: I don't think you can as it is performing the numerator and denominator calculations on the underlying data - not the results. The workarounds you have mentioned.